# Ldap authentication via nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, openldap, docker-ingress

I was using nginx ingress controller in kubernates where i have used customized nginx template file to have settings for ldap authentication by defining ldap_server directive.
At the time of running the nginx ingress controller yaml file,I am getting error below.

```
Unknown directive ldap_server in nginx.templ file.
```

I searched this on web and found that it can be resolved by installing a third party module in nginx like below.

```
./configure --add-module=path_to_http_auth_ldap_module.
```

But How it can be done by nginxingress controller because it does not give direct access to the nginx configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Disappointing, but they are not going to support it:

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1676